# PHP - create class for database access

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I want to create a data access using class. but problem occurs. my document root is public_html so my /resources file is outside document root

i have a data access layer class at /resources/dal/task.php

```
<?php
namespace resources\dal;

class task
{
public $result;
public function __construct()
{
    try {
        # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
        $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root',     'abc123');
        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,     PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING );
    }       
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "I'm sorry. Please try again later.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
    }
}

public function __destruct()
{
    $DBH = null;
}

public function select()
{
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM task");
    $STH->execute();
    $result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->result = $result;
}
}
?>
```

here is my home page (inside public_html) index.php

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/../' . $class . '.php';
    });

use resources\dal as DAL;

$taskClass = new DAL\task();
$result = $taskClass->select();
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

and i get this error:

> Warning: require(D:/DevelopmentWebSite/public_html/../resources\dal\PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\DevelopmentWebSite\public_html\index.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:/DevelopmentWebSite/public_html/../resources\dal\PDO.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\DevelopmentWebSite\public_html\index.php on line 14

i am sorry i am quite new to PHP. anyone has any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I am not very familiar with PHP on Windows but did you tried to change "/" with "\"?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have the PDO extension enabled. If you did, it wouldn't ask your autoloader to load the `PDO` class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using local variable DBH. It means it is lost at end of constructor.

You may to create member variable:
`protected $DBH`

In constructor: `$this->DBH = new PDO(...`

Using: `$this->DBH->prepare(...`

Comment: This is it. i just learned again start from scratch. and i look back this question, it is a silly question. "$this" is very important. thanks user1591984